# std::shared_mutex with std::shared_lock is reader or writer preferring?

Tags: c++, c++17

In implementation of reader-writer lock, we can make use of the `std::shared_mutex` with `std::shared_lock` and `std::lock_guard` or `std::unique_lock`.

**Question**> Is this new feature writer or reader preferring?

Update based on Andrew's comment

[Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex):

```
  // Multiple threads/readers can read the counter's value at the same time.
  unsigned int get() const {
    std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(mutex_);
    return value_;
  }

  // Only one thread/writer can increment/write the counter's value.
  void increment() {
    std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(mutex_);
    value_++;
  }
```

As you can see from above example, I have no control on the reader/writer priority.

Comment: If you implement your own read/write lock, wouldn't that depend on how you implement it?

Comment: @AndrewHenle please check my update question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is neither (if implemented properly).  Instead readers and writers are chosen to be next by a *fair* technique.  And that is the reason that this characteristic is neither settable in the API, nor specified.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13445989/576911) details how that is accomplished.

Answer (score 5):

In practice:

- libc++ always uses the mutex+condition variables technique Howard mentioned, not surprisingly.
- libstdc++ uses `pthread_rwlock_t` where available, falling back to the algorithm Howard mentioned if it is not. Therefore if `pthread_rwlock_t` is available, the algorithm used depends on the pthreads implementation. I believe that glibc prefers readers by default.
- MSVC uses Windows `SRWLOCK`, whose [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa904937(v=vs.85).aspx) says

  > There is no guarantee about the order in which threads that request
  >   ownership will be granted ownership; SRW locks are neither fair nor
  >   FIFO.