# Is there a sort fo weak mutex concept?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14, mutex

Let's consider this piece of code (does not necssarily make sense, it's just a MCVE):

```
class Foo
{
public:
    // this function is thread safe
    void doSomething();
};

static std::mutex mutex;
static std::shared_ptr<Foo> instance;

void workerThread()
{
    while ( true )
    {
        mutex.lock();
        if ( instance )
        {
            instance->doSomething();
        }
        mutex.unlock();
        msleep( 50 );
    }
}

void messupThread()
{
    while ( true )
    {
        mutex.lock();
        instance.reset( new Foo() );
        mutex.unlock();
        msleep( 1000 );
    }
}
```

A `workerThread` do operations on the `Foo` instance. A `messupThread` modifies the instance on which operations should be done.

This code is thread safe.

Problem comes if you start 10 `workerThread`, when one `workerThread` uses the instance, it will lock the other nine one (while `doSomething` is thread safe, they should be able to work concurrently).

Is there a kind of weak mutex/lock mechanism that would make any `workerThread` prevent `messupThread` from changing the instance but would not prevent a concurrent `workerThread` to use it.

I could do this, but I'm wondering if there is an easier way to implement that using standard objects/mechanisms:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    // this function is thread safe
    void doSomething();
};

static int useRefCount = 0;
static std::mutex work_mutex; // to protect useRefCount concurrent access
static std::mutex mutex;      // to protect instance concurrent access
static std::shared_ptr<Foo> instance;

void workerThread()
{
    while ( true )
    {
        work_mutex.lock();
        if ( useRefCount == 0 )
            mutex.lock(); // first one to start working, prevent messupThread() to change instance
        // else, another workerThread already locked the mutex
        useRefCount++;   
        work_mutex.unlock();           

        if ( instance )
        {
            instance->doSomething();
        }

        work_mutex.lock();
        useRefCount--;
        if ( useRefCount == 0 )
            mutex.unlock(); // no more workerThread working
        //else, keep mutex locked as another workerThread is still working
        work_mutex.unlock();

        msleep( 50 );
    }
}

void messupThread()
{
    while ( true )
    {
        mutex.lock();
        instance.reset( new Foo() );
        mutex.unlock();
        msleep( 1000 );
    }
}
```

Comment: I think what you want are [`shared_mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex) - You want `messupThread` to `lock()` / `unlock()` normally and `workerThread` to `lock_shared()` / `unlock_shared()`.

Comment: I believe you may be looking for `std::shared_mutex`.

Comment: This pattern is known as "Single Writer/Multiple Reader".

Comment: This answer may be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185420/is-there-a-shared-lock-guard-and-if-not-what-would-it-look-like/39185510#39185510

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have access to [`std::shared_mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex), it might solve your problem nicely. It is basically a read/write lock but with different nomenclature: shared access vs. unique access.

Let the worker threads take a [shared lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_lock), and let the messup thread take a [unique lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock).

Whether shared access or unique access is preferred, [depends on the implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43309333/stdshared-mutex-with-stdshared-lock-is-reader-or-writer-preferring). So you might see your messup thread starved because of the high number of worker threads taking a shared lock very frequently.

```
// Worker thread:
std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(m_mutex);

// Messup thread:
std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(m_mutex);
```

Note that `std::shared_mutex` is part of the C++17 standard.

Comment: Then you simply use the pthread library and the read-write-mutex therein directly. Or you could use Boost which also provides locking facilities.

Comment: @jpo38 Funny thing is that `std::shared_lock` is part of the C++14 standard. So you could use that in combination with a different `shared_mutex` implementation and replace it once you move on to C++17.

Comment: @jpo38 In `C++14` you have [std::shared_timed_mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_timed_mutex) that works.

Comment: @Galik: Actually, I'm using boost, and it provides shared_mutex. Just had to replace `std` by `boost` in proposed code.

Answer (score 1):

If all threads should be sharing the same single smart-pointer `instance`, it doesn't make much sense to use `std::shared_ptr` to begin with, but rather `std::unique_ptr`.

May I instead suggest that each thread have its *own* `std::shared_ptr`, copied from the global `instance` shared pointer? Then, protected by a lock, you copy from the global shared pointer to the local shared pointer, and when the lock is unlocked you call the `doSomething` function through the local shared pointer.

Perhaps something like

```
void workerThread()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> local_instance;

    while (true)
    {
        {
            std::scoped_lock lock(mutex);
            local_instance = instance;
        }

        if (local_instance)
        {
            local_instance->doSomething();
        }

        msleep(50);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I used `shared_ptr` in the MVCE (to avoid posting code with memory leak), but my original code uses raw pointers...

Comment: @jpo38 Perhaps you should consider to actually *use* shared pointers? :)