# C++ Boost::thread upgradable mutex "try upgrade lock"?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

I implemented boost upgradable mutexes following the top answer here [Example of how to use boost upgradeable mutexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896717/example-of-how-to-use-boost-upgradeable-mutexes)

What I would like to do is to "try" whether or not the upgrade will block: if the upgrade will not block performs the upgrade, otherwise don't lock it and returns.

Is there any function to do so?

Comment: Are you asking about Boost itself? That already has [`try_lock_upgrade()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_concepts.upgrade_lockable)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is :
-bool try_lock_upgrade_for(duration d)
-bool try_lock_upgrade_until(time when)

see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.upgrade_mutex

Comment: Thanks but I am using an ancient version of Boost on default Ubuntu repository. I guess it's not available. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html